# How to extract the file name of an UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to get the `imageNamed` portion of an UIImage. I had previously set the UIImage using `imageNamed` and created an array of UIImages, now I want to enumerate through the array and extract the filename from each, as a test. Is this possible? For example:

```
   for (id key in self.images){
        UIImage *test=key;
      //now do something with test to get its name, how?
    }
```

The reason I am doing this is because my array of animated images is not working and I want to verify that the contained images are in fact legitimately named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Since `UIImage` instance can be created from few sources, the `imageNamed:` is just a shortcut (i.e. one of the ways to instantiate an image). Others are image creation from `CGImage` or just plain data bytes (`NSData`). You should create your own registry of created named images (something like dictionary with `filename => UIImage` key/value pairs).